# If a Rubocop rule is disabled in-line does it need to be re-enabled

Tags: ruby, rubocop

If you [disable a Rubocop rule in-line](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#disabling-cops-within-source-code) and do not re-enable it, will the rule be disabled for all subsequence files or is an in-line disable limited to the scope of the current file?

For example, if I enter this before a couple of methods that I know break the line length rule:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/LineLength
```

Is this rule disable for the rest of the file, or for all subsequent files in the current scan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In-line config is applied to the given file only (just tested it).

Answer (score 31):

You can also disable rubocop with a comment following some code, which disables it *only for that line.* For example:

```
def update # rubocop:disable Style/EmptyMethod
end
```

This can be nice if you want to say "yes I know this method has too many lines" or something without needing to remember to turn the cop back on.

Comment: at first i was looking for a "better" solution - a comment on a line before, like eslint does it; but this made me realize that ruby is so nice, this is even better.