# Can a rubocop check be disabled on certain paths only?

Tags: activeadmin, rubocop

I'm using ActiveAdmin, where the DSL predisposes you to forming large blocks.  Thus, rubocop says:

> Block has too many lines

- I want to warn when non-active-admin files have large blocks.
- I want to [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40259310/263858) [large blocks](http://www.dennyzhang.com/rubocop_errors/#sec-1-10) in ActiveAdmin.
- I do not want to add a [per-file ignore instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37921807/263858), ([docs](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#disabling-cops-within-source-code)):

  ```
  # rubocop:disable BlockLength
  ```
- [Ignoring the whole directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36896588/263858) won't work, since other things could be missed.

I might consider some config for ActiveAdmin that will globally affect all of its registries, but I'd ideally put the config in the rubocop dotfile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable a single cop for a single directory or specific files. Say, in your example, you want to exclude ActiveAdmin files from being inspected by `Metrics/BlockLength`, and your files are located in `app/admin`, you add this to your `.rubocop.yml`:

```
Metrics/BlockLength:
  Exclude:
    - 'app/admin/**/*'
```

Note that this will override the default excludes (rake and spec files.) If you still want them excluded as well, you'll need to add them to your configuration:

```
Metrics/BlockLength:
  Exclude:
    - 'app/admin/**/*'
    - 'Rakefile'
    - '**/*.rake'
    - 'spec/**/*.rb'
```